# How do I know which kernel is handling which .nb file?

Tags: notebooks, kernel, system, kernel-startup

OS : window 10
Mathematica : v12.2

By my mistake, I opened another mathematica kernel, not knowing a kernel was already running.

I created a lot of .nb files and worked on them in another kernel,
while one kernel was already running with many working .nb.

All .nb are still open.

In this state, how can I know which kernel is handling which .nb file?

I guess that there exist ID(a serial?) concept for both kernel and working .nb file.

And I guess that by executing some command on a working .nb, it is possible to figure out the ID of .nb file and the ID of kernel which handles the working .nb.

Comment: There is [$SessionID](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$SessionID.html). See also [SessionTime](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SessionTime.html).

Comment: You can of course also define `$abc=1` (any name you like) in one notebook, then evaluate `$abc` in other notebooks to see whether they have a value for `$abc`.

Comment: Thank you! $SessionID is like an ID for a kernel.

Comment: Also `$ParentLink`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes that you have opened 2 kernels by calling 2 times the frontend. So each kernel is connected to one frontend.

This code highlights all the notebooks linked to the same
FrontEnd :

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, Background] = Pink
```

The color Pink doesn't remain between sessions (because $$FrontEndSession is used, as opposed to $FrontEnd)

Comment: Great. But Pink makes it now very hard to read the code and look at the notebook now. But nice to know there is way to do this.

Comment: @Nasser I have used Pink to be certain that is not the FontColor the reader use, otherwise ...

Comment: It will be better if WRI made a way to just add some text to each notebook, at the very top edge of the notebook, where the menu is, giving the kernel ID it is using. This way no need to change colors, which most likely will not be something many want to do.  So one just have to look at the top and see the ID.

Comment: @Nasser See my edit. ( Maybe you are not aware)